# VBA-Excel Overflow Error due to Long data type

Tags: vba, excel

This may seem too easy, but I am so desperate.

What I need to do is get the **last value** of the column "D" which has a

**big amount of number**, ex. 987654321, the code is fine if the value is only two-digit. I just can't identify the problem.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Value
Sheets("Sheet1").TxtBox1.Value = lastRow
```

Comment: The above code works for me...

Comment: even with big amount of number? like 3000000000? 3million?

Comment: For values like `3000000000` declare `lastRow` as `Double`

Comment: You may want to see this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa189284%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, for such large number you have to declare it as a double.

```
Dim lastRow As Double
```

Alternatively since you want to store it in a textbox you can do 2 things

1. Declare it as a string
2. Store it directly in the Textbox.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub Sample1()
       Dim lastRow As String

       With Sheets("Sheet1")
           lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Value
           .TextBox1.Value = lastRow
       End With
   End Sub

   Sub Sample2()
       With Sheets("Sheet1")
           .TextBox1.Value = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Value
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Long can only handle values up to 2.1B! For any larger values, better use `Double` instead of `Long`

Comment: lol, silly me. Just trying to cope up with the deadline. But THANK YOU SO MUCH for the word DOUBLE.. :D